# How to optimize route using the google direction API

Tags: google-maps

I am using the google direction api to solve the travelling salesman problem.

Apparently the api takes a param called `optimize:true` and then return a `"waypoint_order": [ 1, 0, 2, 3 ]` telling you the best order of waypoints that optimizes the route.

Thing is, when you try to optimize the route, the API just does not work and you get NO_RESULTS.

For instance use this url to see how the API fails when the `optimize:true|` bit gets added.

NOT working (NO_RESULTS error):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&destination=place_id:ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q&waypoints=optimize:true|place_id:ChIJPeqVDlONbEgRk4X1zrUsKDs|place_id:ChIJ_WegsaCYc0gRlCypaxXgLjs|&key=YOUR_KEY

WORKING (but not optimizing):

NOT optimizing url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=place_id:ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI&destination=place_id:ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q&waypoints=place_id:ChIJPeqVDlONbEgRk4X1zrUsKDs|place_id:ChIJ_WegsaCYc0gRlCypaxXgLjs|&key=YOUR_KEY

Does anyone know if they stopped supporting routes optimization?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen it work.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like that is a bug in the DirectionsService when you pass in PlaceIds.  I replicated it with the Javascript API.  Using addresses works:

```
  waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
  location: "Plymouth, UK", // {placeId:"ChIJPeqVDlONbEgRk4X1zrUsKDs"},
  stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
  location: "Bournemouth, UK", // {placeId:"ChIJ_WegsaCYc0gRlCypaxXgLjs"},
  stopover: true
  });
  var request = {
    origin: "London, UK", //{placeId:"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI"},
    destination: "Newquay, UK", //{placeId: "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q"},
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };
```

[fiddle using addresses (returns waypoint order=1,0)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mmjmqg6y/2/)

But the same locations (I used these placeIds to get the addresses above) doesn't work using placeIds:

```
  waypts = [];
  waypts.push({
  location: {placeId:"ChIJPeqVDlONbEgRk4X1zrUsKDs"},
  stopover: true
  });
  waypts.push({
  location: {placeId:"ChIJ_WegsaCYc0gRlCypaxXgLjs"},
  stopover: true
  });
  var request = {
    origin: {placeId:"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI"},
    destination: {placeId: "ChIJh1a5WhEMa0gRY1JU4PEam8Q"},
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  };
```

[fiddle using placeId (returns ZERO_RESULTS](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mmjmqg6y/4/))

*might* be related to this issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 8979: Bug: Can't use combination of placeId and String for origin/destination](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8979)